multi shipping order place using rest api in magento 2.4
I would like to know which APIs we need to use and the parameters required to place multiple orders as a guest customer.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

While Magento 2.4's REST API doesn't directly support placing multi-shipment orders, you can achieve it by mimicking the guest checkout process for each shipment. This involves creating individual guest carts, adding products specific to each shipment, setting unique shipping and billing addresses, selecting shipping methods, and finally placing the orders one by one using the API. Remember to generate an integration token for API access and have product SKUs, shipping methods, and payment method codes handy. This approach requires iterating through each shipment, but extensions or custom development might offer alternative solutions for complex multi-shipment needs.

Hi, how do you create a setShippingMethod ya , which function and classs to use. because I tried using setShippingMethod from \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session  but unable to
